Prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{n^2}}-\frac{\pi}{4}n\right)=\frac{1}{2}$
I came across the above question in a mathematical problem. It is not difficult to see that
$$
\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{r=0}^{n-1}\sqrt{1-\frac{r^2}{n^2}}\right)=\int\limits_0^1\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}{n^2}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{4}.
$$
Nevertheless, the above question asks for estimating the residual of the Riemann sum. By letting $n$ become very large and computing brutely using a program, I suspect that the above limit should be $\frac{1}{2}$, but I have no idea how to prove this result mathematically. Can anybody help me?

Please use a high-level tag like "ca.classical-analysis-and-odes". I added this tag now. Regarding high-level tags, see https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1075/

By the Euler–MacLaurin summation formula for
$$f(u):=f_n(u):=\sqrt{1-u^2/n^2}$$
and $m=2$ (see e.g. formulas (2.1), (2.2), and (2.4) here or here),
$$S:=S_n:=\sum_{r=0}^{n-1}f(r)=A_2+R_2,$$
where
\begin{align}&A_2:=A_{n;2}:= \\ 
&\int_0^{n-1} f(u) \, du+\frac{1}{2} (f(n-1)+f(0))+
\frac{1}{12} \left(f'(n-1)-f'(0)\right) \\
&=
\frac n2\, \Big(\frac{2}{\sqrt{2 n-1}}+\pi \Big)  
+\frac{1}{12n \sqrt{2 n-1}}-\frac{7}{12\sqrt{2n-1}} \\ 
&+n \tan ^{-1}\Big(\frac{n-1}{\sqrt{2 n-1}-n}\Big)+\frac12
\end{align}
and $|R_2|=O(1/\sqrt n)=o(1)$ (as $n\to\infty$).
Note also that
$$A_2-\frac\pi 4\,n\to\frac12.$$
So, the desired result follows.
